# how can we take the benefit of ToValueProvider in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my question is how can we take the advantage of **ToValueProvider** method in asp.net MVC and when to use it?

For example we could use the method

```
TryUpdateModel(d , collection.ToValueProvider());
```

but at the same time it is correct to use it without the second parameter, so what is the role that the **ToValueProvider** method plays at that context.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [sources](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FormCollection.cs) `FormCollection.ToValueProvider` is just:

```
    public IValueProvider ToValueProvider()
    {
        return this;
    }
```

So I think It's just kept for compatibility with older versions of MVC. In MVC 2 it was only possible to use

```
TryUpdateModel(d , formCollection.ToValueProvider());
```

not

```
TryUpdateModel(d , formCollection);
```

In MVC 2 `FormCollection` didn't implement `IValueProvider` and `ToValueProvider` method returned `IDictionary<string, ValueProviderResult>` that is the type of the second parameter of `Controller.TryUpdateModel` in MVC 2. You can see it [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-2/blob/master/MVC/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/FormCollection.cs#L27) and [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-2/blob/master/MVC/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/Controller.cs#L356).

`UpdateModel` with only one parameter searches for values in four places: form data, route data, the query string, and uploaded files. By using overloaded version with two parameters you can specify one of these places (form data for example) or use your own object implementing `IValueProvider` ([this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) on www.asp.net has example).